# Drawing rectangle with line's causes join artifact with the graphics api

Tags: graphics, lua, love2d

how can I join lines to draw rectangles, I get this artifact like this, here's my code:

```
   graphics.line(40,20,30,20)
   graphics.line(30,20,30,30)

   graphics.line(30,30,40,30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing independent and unconnected lines.
What you *probably* want is a polyline.
You can get a polyline by passing in more than two points to the `line` function.
Note the comment for the last argument on the [`line` function documentation](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.line).

Here I render four lines. Three unconnected lines and a four point poly-line.

[image: example result of drawing three unconnected lines and a four point polyline]

*You will notice the artefact renders a bit different from yours. This could be caused by differences between your environment and mine.*

And here is the relevant code to help you understand the difference between both approaches.

```
local graphics = love.graphics

function love.load()
    love.window.setMode(700, 400)
end


function love.draw()
    graphics.scale(10)
    graphics.setLineWidth(2)

    -- unconnected
    graphics.line(30,10, 10,10)
    graphics.line(10,10, 10,30)
    graphics.line(10,30, 30,30)
    
    -- connected
    graphics.line(60,10, 40,10, 40,30, 60,30)
end
```

*I changed the coordinates for the initial three lines a bit to better frame the examples in the screenshot.*